# Javascript Não reconhece as dimensões

Tags: javascript

Isso era pra gerar um quadrado verde na tela, mas não aparece nada... se eu coloco alguma palavra dentro do span ela aparece com o fundo verde, mas não no tamanho que defini no script.
Alguém pode me da uma força ae??

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

`span` ė um elemento do tipo `inline`.

Elementos `inline` tem o tamanho definido por seu conteúdo, mesmo que você atribua um tamanho manualmente.

Muitos atributos do *CSS* só são aplicáveis nas condições certas.

Para dar um tamanho para o `span`, dê a ele a propriedade `display: inline-block`.

Comment: Acho que esse não é o problema, porque tentei a mesma coisa utilizando uma div e o resultado foi o mesmo.